# play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar crash error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have read several articles on play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar crashing in android studio but nothing is helping the issue. I am attaching an image of my screen.

Is there an update or something I should do, I cannot find where the 15.0.1 is referenced in the gradle. It looks like 16.1.0 is the latest version but I am lost right now.

error message I get is gradle sync failed.